# Convert Varchar field to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime-format, sql-server-2017

I am trying to convert varchar date to date time field and having a really hard time. It is giving me:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

or

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I have 2 datetime formats below :

1. Date field looks like `21-12-2009`, `05-10-2005` etc
2. Date field looks like `19-03-2018 14:59`

```
select cast(convert(varchar,Stg_hw.date_of_birth,110)as date)
from Stg_Height_and_Weight Stg_hw
where Stg_hw.person_id = 1620458

select CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(date_of_birth,2)+SUBSTRING(Stg_hw.date_of_birth,4,2)+SUBSTRING(Stg_hw.date_of_birth,7,4)) 
from Stg_Height_and_Weight Stg_hw
where Stg_hw.person_id = 1620458

select cast(Stg_hw.date_of_birth as date)
from Stg_Height_and_Weight Stg_hw
where Stg_hw.person_id = 1620458
```

Answer (score 2):

`CONVERT(DATETIME, DateFieldColumnName, 103)` can help to convert those 2 format to datetime.

Sample exection:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (DateVal VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO TestTable (DateVal) VALUES
('21-12-2009'), ('05-10-2005'), ('19-03-2018 14:59');

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, DateVal, 103) AS Result
FROM TestTable
```

Please find the working demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=59846c37f5b6a4865dec748f59753e51)

Comment: Might be worth commenting on the possible surprising behavior that SQL Server doesn't care if the separator is a dash or slash +1.

Comment: @Doodle If the answer is helped to solve your problem, you may up vote and [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)